# Fast algorithm for computing lower mode shapes and natural frequencies in MATLAB using sparse stiffness and mass matrices

Tags: finite-element, matlab, sparse-matrix, eigenvalues

I am looking for a fast algorithm for computing eigenvalues and eigenvectors from sparse stiffness and mass matrices in MATLAB. The `eig(K, M)` doesn't work with sparse matrices.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html

Comment: Note that if you type `eig(K, M)` in Matlab, with sparse $K$, $M$, the error message itself suggests using `eigs` instead.